# airflow with OpenLDAP - LDAPAttributeError('invalid attribute type ' + attribute_name_to_check) LDAPAttributeError: invalid attribute type memberOf

Tags: authentication, openldap, airflow

Trying to authenticate localsetup of Airflow with local OpenLDAP. But while trying to login from the webserver getting following error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ldap3/core/connection.py", line 751, in search
raise LDAPAttributeError('invalid attribute type ' + attribute_name_to_check)
```

LDAPAttributeError: invalid attribute type memberOf

Error indicates that memberOf is invalid attribute type. my ldap section configuration is:

```
superuser_filter = memberOf=CN=airflow-super-users,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com

data_profiler_filter = memberOf=CN=airflow-data-profilers,OU=Groups,DC=example,DC=com
```

After some search understood that I should have configured the groups with `overley memberOf` attribute. I can't redo my setup with this for getting this functionality. Is there any workaround?

Additionally there is one python package (airflow-alt-ldap) which can help as workaround. but it's not working with airflow 1.8.1 setup

Comment: You can't redo your setup why?

Comment: @EJP  it'll be approval nightmare. So trying to figure out workaround

Answer (score 0):

No. `memberOf` is a feature of the `memberof` overlay. Nothing else.